# GNOMEで追加したアプリのアイコンが表示されない

Tags: linux, gnome

Arch Linux上のGNOMEでアプリケーションのアイコンが表示されません。

Firefox Developer Editionのtar.gzファイルをダウンロードして`$HOME/FirefoxDeveloperEdition`に展開しました。

その後`$HOME/.local/share/applications`
に下記の`.desktop`ファイルを設置したのですがアプリケーションメニューにアイコンが表示されません。
なぜでしょうか?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/username/FirefoxDeveloperEdition/firefox/firefox-bin %u
Icon=/home/username/FirefoxDeveloperEdition/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Comment=Custom definition for FirefoxDeveloperEdition
```

環境:
Arch Linux カーネル 5.7.12
GNOME 3.36.4

Comment: GNOME や OS 自体を再起動してもNGでしょうか？

Comment: 再起動しても表示されませんでした

Comment: xdg-update-databaseなども実行してみたのですが、うまく行かず表示されないです

Comment: ご自身で試したことは質問の本文に直接追記してください。その方が質問一覧でも再度上位に表示されるので、回答してくれるかもしれない人の目に留まりやすくなります。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました:

`desktop-file-install`を使って`desktop`ファイルを登録し、
その後で`update-desktop-database`でデータベースをupdateする必要があるみたいです。

`.desktop`ファイルが~/app.desktopにあり、
`~/.local/share/applications`にデータベースを登録したい場合下記のようになります。

```
desktop-file-install --dir=~/.local/share/applications ~/app.desktop
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```